# Altium Designer - connection of two nets and using vias

Tags: altium, designer

I design a simple PCI-E riser. I need a clue, I'm stuck on a relatively simple element. I would like to connect two power supply lines + 12V (pads B1 and B2) on the top layer and then go through the three passes to the Bottom layer. In addition I wonder how to get the irregular shape of the path visible on the right in the selected rectangle (red color). Shoud I use Polygon Plane?

[image: Photo]

[image]

---

Thanks for your support! I did the following:

1. created Polygon Pour, connect it to Net +12V
2. selected *Pour Over All Same Net Objects*
3. selected Layer: Top Layer

Next I've set proterties of Viases: Net -> +12V.

Is this correct?

I will also use the Interactive Length Tuning function, thank you for the link!

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should definitely use a polygon pour or an internal plane that you can drop the vias down to and connect them together. This is very common practice and has numerous benefits besides just connectivity.

As for the serpentine traces, Altium includes a tool to do this for you called "Interactive Length Tuning". It's used to add length to certain tracks in order to make them match the length of other tracks where timing is critical (i.e. high speed data signals and clocks). You can learn about the tool here:

https://www.altium.com/documentation/18.0/display/ADES/((Length+Tuning))_AD

Answer (score 0):

Using a Polygon is the way to go. You can create design rule to specify the clearance to other traces.